# Adding Host to Cain and Abel Sniffer from Different Subnet?

Tags: windows, subnet, man-in-the-middle

I'm trying to use Cain & Abel to log the network traffic between my domain controller which is a Windows 2008 Server (Machine A) and Windows XP computer (Machine B). They're both installed as virtual machines on an ESXi server I recently bought, and rather than putting them on a NAT, I've configured ESXi to keep them both bridged to my network.

Machine B is on a domain known as 'test.local' with an IP of:

```
    192.14.0.195
```

Machine A is hosting the domain 'test.local' with an IP of:

```
    192.14.0.196
```

My target is to detect the hashes being sent by Machine B to Machine A.

I was able to log traffic using the sniffer + ARP Poising technique. However, I like to learn how to reverse engineer and hack things, and then try writing something to 'patch' or 'prevent' it and since one my of my friends had told me earlier that he had used Cain and Abel to log the same stuff, but when the domain controller had an IP of something like:

```
    192.15.0.198
```

And Machine B had an IP of:

```
    192.14.0.195
```

As you can see there's different subnets. Knowing this is possible, how would I go about accomplishing attacks on the hosts that are on my subnet, but the domain controller is not? I know it is accessible because running 'nslookup' sets it as the default server and traceroutes and pings are successful. I can also RDP to it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!